# CSS Boxes not Responsive when Compressing browser

Tags: css

I have a pretty simple question I can't seem to figure out. I have three boxes that I created on this page: http://www.erglighting.com/index.php/energy_saving_toolkits

However when I compress the browser down the three boxes don't become responsive. For the life of me I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is the code for the three boxes:

```
<div class="wrapper margin-bot1">
  <div class="bg-3">
    <div class="indent">
      <div class="wrapper margin-bot" align="center">ERGL Savings Calculator<img src="http://www.erglighting.com/media/wysiwyg/images/toolkit_artwork1.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="extra-wrap">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="extra-wrap">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <a class="button-1 margin-left" href="http://www.erglighting.com/index.php/retrofit-kits/energy-savings-toolkit/ergl-savings-calculator.html">More...</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-3">
    <div class="indent">
      <div class="wrapper margin-bot">State Incentives (DSIRE)<img src="http://www.erglighting.com/media/wysiwyg/images/toolkit_artwork2.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="extra-wrap">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <a class="button-1 margin-left" href="http://www.erglighting.com/index.php/retrofit-kits/energy-savings-toolkit/state-incentives-dsire.html">More...</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-3">
    <div class="indent">
      <div class="wrapper margin-bot">DLC Product Listings<img src="http://www.erglighting.com/media/wysiwyg/images/toolkit_artwork3.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="extra-wrap">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <a class="button-1 margin-left" href="http://www.erglighting.com/index.php/retrofit-kits/energy-savings-toolkit/dlc-product-listings.html">More...</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is some of the CSS. You can see the full file at the web page link above:

```
.button-1 {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 18px;
  border-radius: 17px;
  -moz-border-radius: 17px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 17px;
  background: url(../images/button-1-2.png) left -82px repeat-x #555;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #747474, #555); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+, iOS 5+ */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #747474, #555); /* FF3.6 */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #747474, #555); /* IE10 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #747474, #555); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #747474, #555);
  padding: 7px 18px 10px 15px;
  margin-left: 79px;
}

/* Global Structure---------------------------------------- */
.main {
  width: 950px;
/ / Reduced this to match with the parent 's width padding : 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}

.extra-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/*----- txt,links,lines,titles -----*/
.fleft {
  float: left
}

.fright {
  float: right
}

.alignright {
  text-align: right
}

.aligncenter {
  text-align: center
}

.alignmiddle * {
  vertical-align: middle
}

.d-in-block {
  display: inline-block;
}

.d-block {
  display: block;
}

.reg {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.reg2 {
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}

.reg3 {
  letter-spacing: -2px;
}

.index {
  z-index: 99;
  position: relative;
}

.rel {
  position: relative;
}

.color1 {
  color: #ff2100;
}

/********************** Content ************************/

.img-indent-l {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 12px 0px 0px;
}

.img-indent-2 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
}

/*********************************boxes**********************************/
.indent {
  padding: 27px 20px 27px 25px;
}

.indent1 {
  padding: 25px 15px 15px 25px;
}

.indent2 {
  padding: 24px 15px 10px 19px;
}

.indent-left {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.indent-bottom {
  padding-bottom: 18px;
}

.indent-bottom1 {
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}

.indent-right {
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.indent-top {
  padding-top: 19px;
}

.indent-top1 {
  padding-top: 39px;
}

.margin-top {
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.margin-top1 {
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.margin-top2 {
  margin-top: -6px;
}

.margin-top3 {
  margin-top: -8px;
}

.margin-top4 {
  margin-top: -4px;
}

.margin-top5 {
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.margin-bot {
}

.margin-bot1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.margin-bot2 {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.margin-bot3 {
  margin-bottom: 21px;
}

.margin-bot4 {
  margin-bottom: 17px;
}

.margin-bot5 {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.margin-bot6 {
  margin-bottom: 19px;
}

.margin-bot7 {
  margin-bottom: 58px;
}

.margin-bot8 {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.margin-bot9 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.margin-bot10 {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.margin-bot11 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.margin-bot12 {
  margin-bottom: 28px;
}

.margin-bot13 {
  margin-bottom: 26px;
}

.margin-bot14 {
  margin-bottom: 62px;
}

.margin-left {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-left: 27px;
}

.margin-left1 {
  margin-left: 16px;
}

.margin-right {
  margin-right: 14px;
}

/*********************************content*************************************/
#content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 60px 0;
  position: relative;
  background: url(../images/bg-5.gif) left top repeat-x #fff;
}

#page1 #content {
  padding-top: 57px;
}
```

Comment: try removing `overflow:visible; position:relative;` from .wrapper

Comment: I tried removing overflow and position and now when I compress the browser down the two on the right disappear. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have fixed widths set on your .main & .grid_24 divs - try setting max-width:950px instead of width:950px.

This is not the complete solution as the individual image blocks are still not compressing, but it's a start.

Comment: Any other suggestion what could cause it not to drop down when compressing the browser?

Comment: Use % for your padding & margin values instead of px